# A word(?) on giving something a different name on media to make it more acceptable?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a word or a phrase that has to do with renaming an act (that is deemed morally questionable) so that it may seem more neutral and therefore acceptable to the general public? It has nothing to do with understating the horrors of what is done, rather it is more on giving it a different label so that the there is more distance between the public and whatever reprehensible act was done, making it an easier pill to swallow.

The only example I could find online is renaming 'acts of torture' with 'abuse' in the Abu Ghraib scandal to make it seem more neutral.

Comment: At the duplicate: 'euphemism'; 'sugar-coating'. At [a word for obscuring bad or immoral acts with verbiage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203387/word-for-obscuring-bad-or-immoral-acts-with-verbiage/203401#203401): 'doublespeak'.